# Cannot connect to rabbitmq STOMP from Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, stomp

I have used the RabbitMQ docker image which has STOMP enabled. With the following configuration, when I try to run my Spring Boot Application, I am getting an exception.

**StackTrace**:

> 2020-11-21 16:03:07.620  INFO 28504 --- [ient-loop-nio-1] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : TCP connection failure in session *system*: Failed to connect: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:61613

> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:61613
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
> at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
> at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:714) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
> at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
> at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
> at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_242]

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM rabbitmq:3-management
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_stomp
EXPOSE 61613
```

The logs from Rabbitmq container looks fine to me.

[image]

**WebSocketConfig.java** looks like:

```
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws-connection")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queue")
            .setRelayPort(61613)
            .setRelayHost("127.0.0.1")
            .setClientPasscode("guest")
            .setClientLogin("guest");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/ws");
}
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

What's wrong with the configuration? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you made a mistake while exposing the rabbitmq stomp port `61613` for the client. By the way, I tested with a similar configuration it works for me.

For implementation please check my demo application on [GitHub](https://github.com/zbytes/rabbitmq-stomp-connection-in-spring-boot) or read the following details.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM rabbitmq:3-management

RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_stomp

EXPOSE 15671 15672 61613
```

**Server Implementation**

*Message Contract*

```
public class ZbytesMessage {

    private String from;
    private String text;

    ...getters and setters...

}
```

*WebSocket Configuration*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class StompConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/zsockets")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queue")
                .setRelayHost("localhost")
                .setRelayPort(61613)
                .setClientLogin("guest")
                .setClientPasscode("guest");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/zbytes");
    }
}
```

*Web Controller*

```
@Controller
public class ZbytesController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ZbytesController.class);

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public ZbytesMessage greeting(ZbytesMessage msg) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
        LOG.info("Received : {} from: {} ", msg.getText(), msg.getFrom());
        return msg;
    }
}
```

*Server Runner*

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServerRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerRunner.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Client Implementation**

```
public class HelloClient {

    private static final WebSocketHttpHeaders headers = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloClient.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HelloClient helloClient = new HelloClient();

        ListenableFuture<StompSession> f = helloClient.connect();
        StompSession stompSession = f.get();

        LOG.info("Subscribing to greeting topic using session {}", stompSession);
        helloClient.subscribeGreetings(stompSession);

        LOG.info("Sending hello message {}", stompSession);
        helloClient.sendHello(stompSession);
        Thread.sleep(60000);
    }

    public ListenableFuture<StompSession> connect() {

        Transport webSocketTransport = new WebSocketTransport(new StandardWebSocketClient());
        List<Transport> transports = Collections.singletonList(webSocketTransport);

        SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);
        sockJsClient.setMessageCodec(new Jackson2SockJsMessageCodec());

        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);

        String url = "ws://{host}:{port}/zsockets";
        return stompClient.connect(url, headers, new MyHandler(), "localhost", 8080);
    }

    public void subscribeGreetings(StompSession stompSession) {
        stompSession.subscribe("/topic/greetings", new StompFrameHandler() {

            public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders stompHeaders) {
                return byte[].class;
            }

            public void handleFrame(StompHeaders stompHeaders, Object o) {
                LOG.info("Received greeting {}", new String((byte[]) o));
            }
        });
    }

    public void sendHello(StompSession stompSession) {
        String jsonHello = "{ \"from\" : \"suraj\", \"text\" : \"Hi zbytes!\" }";
        stompSession.send("/zbytes/hello", jsonHello.getBytes());
    }

    private static class MyHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void afterConnected(StompSession stompSession, StompHeaders stompHeaders) {
            LOG.info("Now connected");
        }
    }

}
```

**To Run**

- Build the docker image and run it (don't forget to expose port 61613). (Note: I would prefer [docker-compose.yaml](https://github.com/zbytes/rabbitmq-stomp-connection-in-spring-boot/blob/main/docker-compose.yaml))

```
docker build -t zbytes/rabbitmq .
docker run -p61613:61613 zbytes/rabbitmq
```

- Run `ServerRunner` java main class.
- Run `HelloClient` java main class.

**Server Output**

```
i.g.zbytes.demo.server.ZbytesController  : Received : Hi zbytes! from: suraj
```

**Client Output**

```
Received greeting {"from":"suraj","text":"Hi zbytes!"}
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. Exposing the port worked for me.

Comment: Thank you I have also got same issue and have spent 3 days trying to solve. Now from your answer when i expose port it works fine with me

Comment: @Bhuwan Prasad Upadhyay, the GitHub repo link is broken, do you know where the demo app lives currently? :-)